# Android UTC stopped working alert

Tags: android

if anyone suffer with this irritating error message like me and have a solution to make it correct without device factory restore.

it shows following error

```
    Unfortunately, UTC has stopped
```

For example here:

[image]

Comment: sorry i am unable to attach screenshot as lack of reputation point. but here a link to my fb account for screenshot

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=879658392096531&set=a.106720019390376.9867.100001571351754&type=1&theater

Comment: Please provide some additional informations. For example: When do you get this error?

Comment: the error occurred all sudden specially while typing in like in whts app messenger a after typing some letters it stops responding and the above error/bug dialogue appeared.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=883928911669479&set=a.106720019390376.9867.100001571351754&type=1&theater

the above link shows you an screen-shot to the aforesaid error please look at @SebastianWalla

Comment: Think you should post this on android stackexchange instead. Flagging for the same.

Comment: Is t his Error occurred at the time of opening a particular app or please add the way of Error occurring.

Answer (score 0):

If this is occurred while you using/Opening an App, that is an App crash.
For this you need to clear your App's Cache, then it will be fine.

I came across this Error, after clearing App cache everything is fine.

Please try these Steps **:**

1. Open the Settings menu and choose Application Manager.
2. Tap the All tab, then look for and tap on the Error prone application.
3. Then select Force Stop, Clear Cache, Clear Data.
4. Restart the phone and all should be well.

This might help you..!!!

Comment: i had tried this, no permanent solution even i had uninstalled it from application manager many times but still persist. and it occurred all sudden now i am thinking of a factory restore as it ruining performance.